# issue with dialogfragment.show()

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I'm having a dialog fragment in my application, that i'm calling like-

```
    dialog=new
     FragmentActivity.dfragment(this);

    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment3).getView()
            .findViewById(R.id.btn1)
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                             dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
                                             System.out.println(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Dialog").getTag());
                     // gives null pointer exception
                }
            });
```

//                      The Dialog frag class.

```
public static class dfragment extends DialogFragment {
    public dfragment(DialogDisplayed dd) {
        super();
        this.dd = dd;
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putBoolean("Value", true);
        setArguments(b);
    }

    DialogDisplayed dd;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getDialog().setTitle("DIALOG FRAGMENT");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, container);
        v.findViewById(R.id.diss).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Setting the bundle",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                dismiss();
                dd.onDialogClicked();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

}
```

I believe it's not able to find the fragment by tag "Dialog" even though the doc says it adds it to the FragManager.
 I'm wonderin why it's giving an exception
thanks

Comment: Could you add a bit more of the code that sets up the fragment please.

Answer (score 0):

You got null reference exception cause

> dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Dialog");

doesn't add your fragment to fragmentManager promptly, but creates FragmentTransaction and schedules commit. This commit will be executed when UI thread will be ready. 
See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit() for details.